# visualizing obstacles in rviz (Gridcells vs map element)

Tags: navigation, rviz, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

I am trying to show obstacles / objects in rviz. i'm using costmap_2d for that

in the video of Using rviz with the Navigation Stack [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack)
obstacles can be shown by using *GridCells* element in rivz (nav_msgs/GridCells).

But in the [costmap_2d](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d) page and in the published topics there is only /grid (nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid). so i should use *map* element in rviz to see obstacles (/costmap topic)

since both of them are related obstacles why the both pages implicate different things? And how can i publish /obstacles topic to choose GRIDCELL display just like the video???

i tried to do plugins but again there's only /costmap topic for me to use.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237988/visualizing-obstacles-in-rviz-(gridcells-vs-map-element)/) by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That tutorial is out of date. You should visualize the costmap using /costmap and /costmap_updates

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2016-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0